# svn: Expected version '3' of repository; found version '5' with up to date svn client

Tags: svn

I'm getting the dread "svn: Expected version '3' of repository; found version '5'" error, but my svn client is up to date (1.6.5, freshly installed from CollabNet)

Why would my svn client be expecting an old repository schema version?  Or is the repository borked somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it *was* a server side problem.  Exact cause and fix unknown (I did ask).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are trying to commit changes but somebody has "committed" since you last updated.  You need to do an update before you can commit.

Comment: no, you're thinking of the svn commit out of date working copy message. This is a different error which happens every time I try and connect to this repository whatever the svn command

Answer (score 0):

run `svn --version` to make absolutely sure that your actually using the new version and not some older version still lying around in your path.
Subversion doesn't show errors like this for no reason.

Comment: svn, version 1.6.15 (r1038135)
   compiled Nov 29 2010, 16:11:54